# A chat client using the Android NDK in c++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, chat

I need to connect multiple android devices through a chat client using the NDK in c++. I did the communication through the SDK in Java for a client and server but need assistance to connect through the NDK in c++.

Comment: show us what you've tried. Where's your exact problem?

Comment: Give some code samples, java and/or c++.

Comment: I'm developing a game using cocos2d-x and I need to make it multiplayer. I'm trying to do this using a chat application. Since I have to make it cross platform I have to do the development in c++. I followed a online tutorial to develop the chat using java and it only connects to the server. I followed this tutorial for it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgOrhLu5XUo

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your level, but I assume that you are not feeling comfortable using C++, the I am sure that Poco can help you: http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf

Comment: Yes, I'm new to c++ so appreciate your help and I'll look into this.